# when people clicked paypal buy button,If users didn't logged in website, it redirect login.php

Tags: button, paypal, click

I have a paypal buy button.But when Everyone clicked button, they can buy products.But I want that users logged in website.I didn't success it.What can i do for it? I mean If users don't log in website and clicked buy button, it redirect login.php

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

Either don't show the buy button unless they are logged in or modify your checkout system to be able to handle orders without an account.

Comment: I thought it too.But are there another way?

Comment: The only other way I can think of would be to do an auto-login based on the email they used at PayPal, but that would be highly insecure.